# How to pass an array to a function in VBA?

Tags: arrays, function, ms-access, vba

I am trying to write a function that accepts an array as an argument. The array can have any number of elements.

```
Function processArr(Arr() As Variant) As String
    Dim N As Variant  
    dim finalStr as string      
    For N = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
        finalStr = finalStr & Arr(N)
    Next N
    processArr = finalStr
End Function
```

Here is how I try to call the function:

```
Sub test()
    Dim fString as string
    fString = processArr(Array("foo", "bar"))
End Sub
```

I get an error saying:

> Compile Error: Type mismatch: array or user defined type expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sometimes the ByRef keyword helps as well: `Function test(ByRef arr() As Variant)`

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This seems unnecessary, but VBA is a strange place. If you declare an array variable, then set it using `Array()` then pass the variable into your function, VBA will be happy.

```
Sub test()
    Dim fString As String
    Dim arr() As Variant
    arr = Array("foo", "bar")
    fString = processArr(arr)
End Sub
```

Also your function `processArr()` could be written as:

```
Function processArr(arr() As Variant) As String
    processArr = Replace(Join(arr()), " ", "")
End Function
```

If you are into the whole brevity thing.

Comment: The dude abides

Comment: Well, I guess I've seen something every bit as stupefying as you can see in any of those other places, and in English, too.

Answer (score 33):

Your function worked for me after changing its declaration to this ...

```vb
Function processArr(Arr As Variant) As String
```

You could also consider a `ParamArray` like this ...

```vb
Function processArr(ParamArray Arr() As Variant) As String
    'Dim N As Variant
    Dim N As Long
    Dim finalStr As String
    For N = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
        finalStr = finalStr & Arr(N)
    Next N
    processArr = finalStr
End Function
```

And then call the function like this ...

```vb
processArr("foo", "bar")
```

Comment: The reference for ParamArray is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-parameter-arrays  Interesting that VBA doesn't even highlight ParamArray or change the case.