# ByRef Argumenttype mismatch when passing an array to a sub or function

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, string, byref

I am working on a little project for work. All I am trying to do is create an array in Sub1 and call a function, pass the array to that function and have it fill the array.

Very simplified, it looks something like this:

```
Private Sub whatever()
  Dim arr(10, 2) As String
  workArray arr
End Sub

Sub workArray(ByRef arr As String)
  '- do stuff here
End Sub
```

I have googled so much and just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I have also tried:

- call workArray(arr)
- call workArray arr
- workArray(arr)
- workArray arr

I've read that I can only pass an array ByRef, so I am sure that should be alright. The array arr is of type String, the array the function expects is declared as String - that should be alright too. I always get "ByRef argument type mismatch". Is the problem maybe with the type of String? Are String-arrays behaving differently?

Anyone in here kind enough to release me of my pain?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass an array to a function in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26492872/how-to-pass-an-array-to-a-function-in-vba)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `()` in the function, an array needs `()` after the variable when passing it somewhere else so VBA knows it as an array

```
Private Sub whatever()
  Dim arr(10, 2) As String
  workArray arr
End Sub

Sub workArray(ByRef arr() As String)
  '- do stuff here
End Sub
```

### Edit

I look around a little bit [cperson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/passingandreturningarrays.htm) has an excellent in depth guide on passing arrays to functions and back again. When in doubt, check cperson. He has a load of useful stuff regarding VBA

Comment: Hello Mr. Burns, thank you very much for your answer! Now I get error code 13 - type mismatch. AND I edited my post, maybe my mistake is somewhere else?

Comment: @McMuellermilch You now have a new issue, I recommend a new question. SO is to help everyone, present or future. My answer is now invalid when looking at your question now. I recommend rolling back your question to what it was originally and if my answer resolved that issue, mark it as accepted and then ask a new question with your new issue